# How SharedPreferences getFirstRun(false) when bulk data has been entered to SQLite in PreLoad?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, preload

My App can insert bulk data from text to SQLite with DatabaseHelper.java extends SQLiteOpenHelper and PreLoadActivity.java extends AsyncTask (Load data in background with Progress Bar). But something get wrong when I open My App every time it always load data. I use SharedPreferences in My App.

This is the code.

AppPreference.java

```
public class AppPreference {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;

    public AppPreference(Context context) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setFirstRun(Boolean input) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        String key = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_first_run);
        editor.putBoolean(key, input);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public Boolean getFirstRun() {
        String key = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_first_run);
        return prefs.getBoolean(key, true);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java (snippet code)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kamus.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static DatabaseHelper instance;
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ENGLISH);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_INDONESIA);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if (instance != null)
            db.close();
    }

    public void insertEnglish(ArrayList<EnglishIndonesiaModel> kamusEnglish) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (EnglishIndonesiaModel data : kamusEnglish) {
                Log.d("tag", "insert eng: " + data.getWord());
                insertDataEnglish(data.getWord(), data.getTranslate());
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.e("tag", "error " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    public void insertIndonesia(ArrayList<IndonesiaEnglishModel> kamusIndonesia) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (IndonesiaEnglishModel data : kamusIndonesia) {
                Log.d("tag", "insert ina:  " + data.getKata());
                insertDataIndonesia(data.getKata(), data.getTerjemahan());
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.e("tag", "eror " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

PreLoadActivity.java (snippet code)

```
public class PreloadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView tvLoading;

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preload_activity);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        tvLoading = findViewById(R.id.tv_loading);

        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(PreloadActivity.this);
        new LoadData().execute();
    }

private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        final String TAG = LoadData.class.getSimpleName();
        AppPreference appPreference;
        double progress;
        double maxProgress = 100;

 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onpre");
            appPreference = new AppPreference(PreloadActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Log.d(TAG, "doinbackground");

            ArrayList<EnglishIndonesiaModel> kamusEnglish = preLoadEnglishRaw(R.raw.english_indonesia);
            ArrayList<IndonesiaEnglishModel> kamusIndonesia = preLoadRaw(R.raw.indonesia_english);

            databaseHelper.insertEnglish(kamusEnglish);
            databaseHelper.insertIndonesia(kamusIndonesia);

            Boolean firstRun = appPreference.getFirstRun();
            if (firstRun) {

                Log.d("tag", "eng_ind size " + kamusEnglish.size());
                Log.d("tag", "ind_eng size " + kamusIndonesia.size());

                progress = 30;
                publishProgress((int) progress);
                Double progressMaxInsert = 100.0;
                Double progressDiff = (progressMaxInsert - progress) / kamusEnglish.size() + kamusIndonesia.size();

                // When DatabaseHelper.close() or insert Data SQLiteDatabase endTransaction() or setTransactionSuccessfull() then AppPreference.setFirstRun(false)
                ...................
                ...................
                ...................

                appPreference.setFirstRun(false);

                progress += progressDiff;
                publishProgress((int) maxProgress);

            } else {
                tvLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        this.wait(2000);
                        publishProgress(50);

                        this.wait(2000);
                        publishProgress((int) maxProgress);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            return "data inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PreferenceManager and SharedPreferences are different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed in checking the condition.
If `firstRun` has done then do not call `AsyncTask` at all .

```
AppPreference appPreference = new AppPreference(PreloadActivity.this);
Boolean firstRun = appPreference.getFirstRun();
    if(firstRun) {
        new LoadData().execute();
 }
```

And inside `doInBackground()` set `setFirstRun(false)`.

```
appPreference.setFirstRun(false);
```

Comment: Did you mean this code move to inside onCreate() method? 

`Boolean firstRun = appPreference.getFirstRun();
    if(firstRun) {
        new LoadData().execute();
 }`

Comment: Yeah  . and  setFirst run as `false` inside `doInBackground()`.

Comment: My App keep error when I edit with this code. Can you provide clear code about this?

Comment: This is clear code you just need to instantiate appPreference at class level or inside oncreate .

Comment: `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preload_activity);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        tvLoading = findViewById(R.id.tv_loading);

        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(PreloadActivity.this);
        Boolean firstRun = appPreference.getFirstRun();
        if (firstRun) {
            new LoadData().execute();
        }
    }`

Comment: Error when debug @adm.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zebhi.kamusbahasa/com.zebhi.kamusbahasa.PreloadActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean com.zebhi.kamusbahasa.helper.AppPreference.getFirstRun()' on a null object reference.


**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean com.zebhi.kamusbahasa.helper.AppPreference.getFirstRun()' on a null object reference
        at com.zebhi.kamusbahasa.PreloadActivity.onCreate(PreloadActivity.java:45)**

Answer (score 0):

```
public SharedPreferences pref;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private final String myPreference = "login";
private String firstTime = "firstTime";

public Method(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    pref = activity.getSharedPreferences(myPreference, 0); // 0 - for private mode
    editor = pref.edit();
}

if (!pref.getBoolean(firstTime, false)) {
      editor.putBoolean(firstTime, true);
      editor.commit();
}

you can get value pref.getBoolean(firstTime, false) // retun true allways

if(pref.getBoolean(firstTime, false)){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you AppPreference code like this:

```
prefs= context.getSharedPreferences(your_preference_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: In this case, I need to edit my PreLoad not AppPreference.

Comment: No, you need to change your AppPreference

Comment: In your AppPreference constructor, replace your code with mentioned code

Comment: in your_preference_name provide warning "Expression expected"?

Comment: I use this code.
`public AppPreference(Context context) {
        prefs= context.getSharedPreferences(AppPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.context = context;
    }`

Comment: public AppPreference (Context context)
{
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
this.context = context;
}

Comment: It still always import the data to sqlite every I open my App. The problem  is how this App import data for the first time launch only. For secondly and so on my app doesn't import data anymore.